# sequence creation in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to create a sequence in oracle where the max value of the column field (Empid) must be the min value of the sequence.

The below was the one i found in our same stackexchange

```
create sequence mytemp_seq start with &v_Startval;
```

This command prompts me to enter the max value of teh column name which i have to enter.

How can I fix the value of &v_startval with out it prompting ,but directly setting the values from the below statement

```
select max(empid) from mytemp..
```

I am trying like this below

```
create sequence mytemp_seq start with (SELECT MAX(empid) from mytemp)
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: Both answers (Tony Andrews and schurik) below are good in different circumstances.  If this is part of a deployment script, I would use schurik's answer, as it will produce a more descriptive spool file.  If you're going to be doing this as a regular activity, I would embed Tony's answer in a package (and question the design; creating sequences dynamically is usually a result of a poor design decision).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do it with some PL/SQL:

```
declare
  v_startval integer;
begin
  select max(empid)+1 into v_startval from mytemp;
  execute immediate 'create sequence mytemp_seq start with ' || v_startval;
end;
```

Answer (score 6):

In sqlplus you can do

```
col max_id new_value seq_min_val  
SELECT MAX(empid)+1 AS max_id from mytemp;
create sequence mytemp_seq start with &seq_min_val;
```